# NullReference when Show a MvxTabBarViewController mvvmcross ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitabbarcontroller, mvvmcross, sidebar

I have a storyboard made on xCode, and know I'm working on visual studio with Xamarin and **mvvmcross**, to do the IOS and the Android app with the same Core.
My StoryBoard have some views (including a SideBar on some of the initial views) that will open 4 views that will call `ShowViewModel` for a `MvxTabBarViewController`, and each one of that view will open a different tab.

All the Navigation to that 4 view, its done, now I have problems Showing the Tab Bar...

When I try to do a simple test of call `ShowViewModel` to `MvxTabBarViewController` and open a specific tab, on the `ViewDidLoad` of that tab, I have the error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

The structure of my Tab bar was all created on the storyboard.

Here is the code of my **TabBarController**:

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, true)]
public partial class TabDetailView : MvxTabBarViewController<TabDetailViewModel>
{
    private bool _constructed;

    public TabDetailView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        _constructed = true;

        // need this additional call to ViewDidLoad because UIkit creates the view before the C# hierarchy has been constructed
        ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public TabDetailView()
    {
        _constructed = true;

        // need this additional call to ViewDidLoad because UIkit creates the view before the C# hierarchy has been constructed
        ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        if (!_constructed)
            return;

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var vm = (TabDetailViewModel)this.ViewModel;
        if (vm == null)
            return;
    }

}
```

And Here is the code of my ViewController corresponding to the Tab that I want to open:

```
 [MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, true)]
public partial class TabDiaryView : MvxViewController<TabDiaryViewModel>
{
    public TabDiaryView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad(); //HERE IS THE ERROR (NULLREFERENCE)
    }
}

public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, IMvxIosViewPresenter presenter)
        : base(applicationDelegate, presenter)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }

    protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
    {
        return new MvxSidebarPresenter((MvxApplicationDelegate)ApplicationDelegate, Window);
    }
}
```

Please help me!!